# Catkin_make error with geometry2 package

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm attempting to use catkin_make to build the 'imu_tools' package [found here](http://wiki.ros.org/imu_tools). But when runnings catkin_make I get the error down below.

```
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "tf2_geometry_msgs"
  with any of the following names:

    tf2_geometry_msgsConfig.cmake
    tf2_geometry_msgs-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "tf2_geometry_msgs" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "tf2_geometry_msgs_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
  files.  If "tf2_geometry_msgs" provides a separate development package or
  SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  imu_tools/imu_filter_madgwick/CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)

-- Could not find the required component 'tf2_geometry_msgs'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
```

My main issue is that I dont really understand what the error message is trying to tell me. I've found the package [(geometery2)](http://wiki.ros.org/geometry2) that I should install somewhere, but I'm struggling to figure out how to do it properly.

Sorry if this is a very basic question, I'm still very new to ROS, and programming in general. Feel free to ask for more information.

Thanks for your time

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288091/catkin_make-error-with-geometry2-package/) by [TheMilkman](https://answers.ros.org/users/33305/themilkman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2018-04-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are right in thinking that you are missing packages. You could manually install them, but this could be time consuming if you are missing a bunch of them. You can use [rosdep](http://wiki.ros.org/rosdep) to automatically install ros
dependencies for a given package. Once you've installed rosdep (instructions in link above), you can move into the top level of your catkin workspace and run the command `rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src -r -y`, which will automatically install all of the deps that you need for imu_tools.

---

Originally posted by [stevejp](https://answers.ros.org/users/33828/stevejp/) with karma: 929 on 2018-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TheMilkman](https://answers.ros.org/users/33305/themilkman/) on 2018-04-09**:
That worked!

I was trying to use rosdep to install the dependencies earlier except I was using `rosdep install imu_tools` which said it installed dependencies, but really didn't. Could you explain that command that worked?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-10**:
@stevejp's answers is the correct one, but I just wanted to point to #q252478 as an example workflow that shows how to build packages from sources.

If you really must build things from sources (instead of using `apt-get`), that is.

**Comment by [TheMilkman](https://answers.ros.org/users/33305/themilkman/) on 2018-05-28**:
That's a really informative answer, would be great if it was a part of the tutorial or something